# Finding the accumulation points of $A=[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm having some trouble finding the set of all accumulation points of $A=[0,1]$. I already prove that $0$ and $1$ are accumulation points, but I can't find a way to prove that any $p \in(0,1)$ is also an accumulation point.

If anyone could help me, it would be great.

Thank you very much!

Comment: If $p\in (0,1)$, you can certainly find a sequence in $(0,1)$ that approaches $p$.

Comment: You can't take the constant sequence since you want a deleted neighborhood.

Comment: @chhro You're right, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every point of $[0,1]$ is an accumulation point. To see this, let $x\in[0,1]$. If $\varepsilon>0$, do you understand why the intersection $\big((x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)\setminus\{x\}\big)\cap[0,1]$ is non-empty? If so, you understand that $x$ is an accumulation point of $[0,1]$.

On the other hand, any point outside $[0,1]$ is not an accumulation point. Indeed, if $x\not\in[0,1]$, then we can find $\delta>0$ so that $(x-\delta,x+\delta)\cap[0,1]=\emptyset$.

Comment: So, I can't really understand why $\big((x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)\setminus\{x\}\big)\cap[0,1]$ is non-empty. Actually, I have a feeling, but I don't know the formal proof.

Comment: @PedroCrispim well, for example, if $x\in(0,1)$ and $\varepsilon$ is small enough, then $(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)\subset(0,1)$. I assume you know that intervals of positive length contain more than 1 single point, right?

Answer (score 0):

Consider any neighbourhood of $p$ of the form $(p-a,p+b),a,b>0$. If $p-a\ge0$, then $\frac{p+(p-a)}2\in A\cap(p-a,p+b)$. Otherwise if $p+b\le1$, then $\frac{p+(p+b)}2\in A\cap(p-a,p+b)$. If the above is not true, then $A\subset(p-a,p+b)$ and $\frac p2\in A\cap(p-a,p+b)=A$.